# Paypal sandbox INVALID_RESOURCE_ID RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: paypal

I got resource not found error when run on a sandbox version but it work find when run on a live.
can someone please advise how can I resolve the error?

here's my code

```html
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"plan_id\": \"P-97A61885CU957844JMFV\",\n  \"start_time\": \"2021-10-19T00:00:00Z\",\n   \"shipping_amount\": {\n    \"currency_code\": \"USD\",\n   \"custom_id\": \"xxxxdxxx\",\n   \"value\": \"10.00\"\n  },\n  \"subscriber\": {\n    \"name\": {\n      \"given_name\": \"John\",\n      \"surname\": \"Doe\"\n    },\n    \"email_address\": \"customer@example.com\",\n    \"shipping_address\": {\n      \"name\": {\n        \"full_name\": \"John Doe\"\n      },\n      \"address\": {\n        \"address_line_1\": \"2211 N First Street\",\n        \"address_line_2\": \"Building 17\",\n        \"admin_area_2\": \"San Jose\",\n        \"admin_area_1\": \"CA\",\n        \"postal_code\": \"95131\",\n        \"country_code\": \"US\"\n      }\n    }\n  },\n  \"application_context\": {\n    \"brand_name\": \"SAMPLEBRAND\",\n    \"locale\": \"en-US\",\n    \"shipping_preference\": \"SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS\",\n    \"user_action\": \"SUBSCRIBE_NOW\",\n    \"payment_method\": {\n      \"payer_selected\": \"PAYPAL\",\n      \"payee_preferred\": \"IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED\"\n    },\n    \"return_url\": \"https://sample.com/webhook_paypal.php\",\n    \"cancel_url\": \"https://sample.com/webhook_paypal.php\"\n  }\n}");

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
    $headers[] = 'Paypal-Request-Id: SUBSCRIPTION-21092019-001';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    
    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> P-97A61885CU957844JMFV

Create such a Plan ID (and Product ID) for the sanbox environment, using the appropriate sandbox account, and use those sandbox IDs instead.  You can do so either via https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing (logging in with the sandbox account's credentials), or via API (using the sandbox account's client ID and secret)

---

Live Plan IDs will never work to create subscriptions in the sandbox environment, nor sandbox ones for the live environment. The two environments are completely separate.

Manage your [sandbox accounts](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) and [sandbox apps](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) in the developer.paypal.com dashboard.